# Como soluciono este error: (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") en mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Ninguna de las preguntas similares formuladas hasta el momento dan soluciòn a mi problema
'''

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
pertenece_categoria varchar(40) not null,
nombre_producto varchar(50) not null,
marca varchar(35) not null,
medida varchar(10) not null,
precio int not null,
estado boolean default 0,
foreign key (pertenece_categoria) references categorias(nombre)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

el código de la tabla que estoy referenciando es asi (ya esta creada):

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `nombre` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: un error en mi pregunta es que estaba referenciando al campo ID, no era a ese al que me refiero si no al campo 'nombre' de la tabla categorias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que `nombre` no es un **indice** (`INDEX o UNIQUE o etc`) en la tabla `categorias`. Solo tenes que agregar, por ejemplo, `, INDEX(nombre)` en la definición de la tabla.

#### Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   INDEX(nombre)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/555011)</kbd>

Comment: funciono copiando tu codigo, GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 1):

Si el orden de creación de las tablas es el que mencionas:

- Categorías
- Productos

Debes llevar a cabo estos cambios:

- Las columnas a relacionar deben ser del mismo tipo de dato, entonces decide si serán `VARCHAR` o `INTEGER`
- Segundo deben ser de la misma longitud
- Deberás agregar como índice tu llave foránea

Código

Tabla categorias

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `nombre` varchar(40) NOt null
) ;
```

Tabla productos

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
    pertenece_categoria varchar(40) not null,
    nombre_producto varchar(50) not null,
    marca varchar(35) not null,
    medida varchar(10) not null,
    precio int not null,
    estado boolean default 0,
    index(pertenece_categoria),
    foreign key (pertenece_categoria) references 
    categorias(nombre)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

Comment: tanto el campo "pertenece_categoria" de la tabla "productos" como "nombre" de la tabla "categorias" son de tipo VARCHAR de 40 caracteres de longitud.

Comment: Probe borrando la tabla y creadola como PRIMARY como dijo un compañero, tambien probe con UNIQUE: CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
    `nombre` varchar(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ; pero el error es siempre el mismo: (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: si, borre toda la base y copie el codigo que me pasaste:  CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
    `nombre` varchar(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ;

CREATE TABLE productos(
    pertenece_categoria varchar(40) not null,
    nombre_producto varchar(50) not null,
    marca varchar(35) not null,
    medida varchar(10) not null,
    precio int not null,
    estado boolean default 0,
    index(pertenece_categoria),
    foreign key (pertenece_categoria) references 
    categorias(nombre)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;

Comment: por si lo anterior era ilegible: https://imgur.com/sSGxPWP

Comment: Es la misma, solo que usando el código que me pasaste, ya que borre las anteriorres para asegurarme de que no estuviera copiando algo mal.

Answer (score 1):

Como han enunciado en las demás respuestas:
1. Los campos relacionados deben tener la misma longitud y tipo de dato. En tu caso ambos son 'VARCHAR(40)'.

Pero...no veo que en la tabla `categorias` tengas definido el campo `nombre` como primary-key y tampoco como un `unique` key. Para hacer referencias, debes tener un campo (o varios, si es un key compuesto) marcado como indice.

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  pertenece_categoria varchar(40) not null,
  nombre_producto varchar(50) not null,
  marca varchar(35) not null,
  medida varchar(10) not null,
  precio int not null,
  estado boolean default 0,
  foreign key (pertenece_categoria) references categorias(nombre)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `nombre` varchar(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es al campo que estás referenciando.
Lo más común es que se referencíe siempre al `id` de la otra tabla, en este caso sería mucho mejor ponerlo como

```
...
pertenece_categoria int not null,
...
foreign key (pertenece_categoria) references categorias(id)
```

Si es necesario referenciarlo hacía el nombre, este debe ser único en la tabla de categorías

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `nombre` varchar(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Ya que de poder repetirse la tabla no sabrá a cual de todos los registros hacer la referencia.

Comment: ya probe agregando el atributo 'UNIQUE' al campo nombre, pero sigue saliendo el mismo error: